# Memcached refuse connection after node upgrade to v18.7.0

Tags: node.js, connection, memcached

I am using memcached locally to store user sessions.
To work with memcached I use the npmjs.com/package/memcached

After upgrading nodes to version v18.7.0, the server stopped connecting to memcached at localhost:11211

However, when the address is changed to 127.0.0.1:11211, the connection proceeds normally, but an error still occurs during further work:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:11211
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
  [stack]: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:11211\n' +
    '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16)',
  [message]: 'connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:11211',
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 11211
}
```

What could be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that memcached was configured to accept connections only via IPv4.
After adding in the settings for receiving connections via IPv6, everything worked.